# UILabel on multiple rows auto centers text though i want it to maintain the text's position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I have a UILabel on multiple rows. The thing is that the number of rows varies and i don't know to maintain the place of the text from the label ( the label auto-centers the text in it's width and height ) . Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find the length that can be fitted within the bounds of the label. Check out [this link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/truncate-an-nsstring-and-append-an-ellipsis-respecting-the-font-size.html) which shows how to find length of a string to be displayed with a particular font.

Answer (score 2):

I am also face this problem ,but i solve this set no of lines 0 for that label  and line break mode is Word wrap finally give max width and height to that label.
i think it will work fine. 
thank you